# What are acceptable communities for a noachide to integrate himself into?

Tags: gentiles, marriage, noachide-laws, communities, noahidism

This is more of a personal question, but undoubtedly applicable for anyone in my situation.

I am a Noachide, and I will not convert to Judaism any time soon because the obligation upon men is way too burdensome for me to handle, to the point where I could not honestly convert with a clean conscious, knowing full well that I would have every intention to skip every morning prayer. (They drive me insane and make me extremely depressed and bored, while subsequently being angry at myself that I hate and despise them.)

Trouble is, there is no community of Noachides that I can find, and I am getting up there in age, and without a community, there are no mates. The first law in the Torah is given to all mankind, to be fruitful and multiply, and so I am getting really angry at myself for not fulfilling this commandment.

And the problem with the Jewish Community is that I obviously can not be marrying Jewish girls, because again; I could never be an honest convert, and I would assume that is a prohibition for Jewish Women, so I would not want to be leading them into sin.

Growing up Protestant, I have not set foot in Churches since I found out that it is considered idolatry (although I think most Christians today would detest the idea of using a cross as an idol, but that is neither here nor there). As a result, I have no community to speak of, and it is kind of killing me inside. I left behind my Protestant community a long time ago, and the odds of running into a good woman on the streets is virtually nil.

So I was thinking to myself: I am a Noachide, how about starting to attend an Orthodox Christian Church, so maybe I could actually find a good G-d-fearing woman?

And if that is prohibited, what other choices do I have in an increasingly secular society?

Comment: Some Noahide communities and further resources are listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noahidism#External_links

Comment: Good luck to you. I hope you get some sound and helpful ideas here.

Comment: An Orthodox Christian church probably would not reap any woman better than one from a Protestant congregation.

Comment: http://www.en.noahideworldcenter.org/ These guys seem to be the people who followed Vendyl Jones?

Comment: @ezra why? They would have more direction and discipline as well as conservative dress no?

Comment: Hi I know rabbi Amos sherki (the rabbi I most respect :-) )has a community abroad. Here is his site http://www.en.noahideworldcenter.org any way good luck and warm hugs!

Comment: @Akiva - Protestant theology is closer to the views of Judaism; thus they would have an easier time adapting. By the way, their are some pretty conservative protestant churches out their, you just have to look. Also, do not think I am trying to lead you down the path towards Christianity again, I'm just offering some advice.

Comment: @ezra Epistemologically, it would be nigh impossible to consider Christianity. Archetypically though, (Been watching Jordan Peterson), I am taking a new look at it. I do find it surprising that you would consider protestantism, which has no anchor or oral tradition to speak of, that you would consider it more like Judaism. Why do you say that?

Answer (score 2):

Seattle, Washington has a number of Noachides.  There was an active community that I was involved with in the past.  It may still be active today.